# Where is RavenDB system database stored physically?

Tags: c#, database, filesystems, ravendb

Where is this being stored physically?

I can see where the user created database gets stored, how do I find out where the data for the system database is being stored?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you check in the folder that the `Raven/DataDir` key is set to, in the `app.config` file for RavenDB ?

Default is as follows.

```
<add key="Raven/DataDir" value="~\Data"/>
```

So it would be in a Data folder under your root installation.

Source: http://ravendb.net/docs/server/administration/configuration

Comment: This is the right folder. I was looking at the wrong instance of RavenDB and hence why the earlier comment. Marked as answer.